# Как узнать, что находится внутри объекта?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть некий объект:

```
var obj = {
    x: 5,
    y: 3
}
```

Допустим, есть функция, у которой задача считать данные с этого объекта, но она не знает, что внутри объекта. Поэтому задача функции - сначала узнать, что внутри, затем все значения считать. Вопрос: как это сделать?

**PS**:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Также, как с массивом

```
for (var n in obj) {
  var 
    key = n,
    type = typeof(obj[n]),
    value = obj[n];
  // alert('obj.'+key+' = ('+type+') '+value);
  // code
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все верно!